# GetToken in WSDL by passing login credentials

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

WSDL url is: `http://test.ipayamex.lk/ibremitws/services/ibagentservice?wsdl`

And to get token, there is a method called: `getToken()`

**PHP**

```
$soap_client = new SoapClient("http://test.ipayamex.lk/ibremitws/services/ibagentservice?wsdl");
$token = $soap_client->getToken();
```

But, the Error code shows message format error. How can I pass login parameters along with this method. In simulator, I can run below method. I don't know how to pass these parameters in terms of PHP coding. Thanks for any kind of help. I am new in WSDL

```
<TRX_MESSAGE>       
<MESSAGE>   
<MESSAGE_ID>RMT_TOKEN_REQ</MESSAGE_ID>      
<USR_NAME>xyz</USR_NAME>      
<AGENT_CODE>111</AGENT_CODE>      
<PASSWORD>123</PASSWORD>      
<AUTH_CODE>abc</AUTH_CODE>
<IP>127.0.0.1</IP> 
</MESSAGE>  
</TRX_MESSAGE>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data type of request is `string` and for response is also `string`.
Now, I need to pass that message in string:
Something like this:

```
    $soap_client = new SoapClient("http://test.ipayamex.lk/ibremitws/services/ibagentservice?wsdl");
    $get_token_message = "<TRX_MESSAGE>
                            <MESSAGE>
                            <MESSAGE_ID>RMT_TOKEN_REQ</MESSAGE_ID>
                            <USR_NAME>xyz</USR_NAME>
                            <AGENT_CODE>111</AGENT_CODE>
                            <PASSWORD>123</PASSWORD>
                            <AUTH_CODE>abc</AUTH_CODE>
                            <IP>127.0.0.1</IP>
                            </MESSAGE>
                          </TRX_MESSAGE>";
    $result = $soap_client->getToken(array('msg'=>$get_token_message));
    $token = $result->getTokenReturn;
    echo $token;
```